# Building an XML App.Config file on button click

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

I'm trying to build out a solution to build an App.config file to access a mySQL Database. I don't want the connection string to be saved in plain text in the XML file. So I figured that a solution to this problem would be to build the App.Config file at login, and at log out wipe the connection string in App.Config. It might not be the most elegant solution, but I am still learning how this works.
Below is the code I am working with and my XML file so far.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Build the new connection string
                StringBuilder Con = new StringBuilder("Server = myServer; Port = 3306; Database = foo;");
                Con.Append("user= " + textBox1.Text + ";");
                Con.Append("password= " + textBox2.Text + ";");
                string strCon = Con.ToString();
                updateConfigFile(strCon);
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Check your connection settings and try again.");
            }

            
            void updateConfigFile(string a)
            {
                try
                {
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\343GuiltySpark\source\repos\MysqlTesting\App.config");
                    //here to verify file loading 
                    MessageBox.Show("File loaded Successfully!");

                    foreach (XElement cell in doc.Element("Configurations").Elements("Configuration"))
                    {
                        if (cell.Element("connectionStrings").Value == "")
                        {
                            cell.Element("connectionStrings").Value = a;
                        }
                    }
                    doc.Save(@"C:\Users\343GuiltySpark\source\repos\MysqlTesting\App.config");
                }
                catch (Exception ep)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ep.Message);
                }
            }
                
        

            var conn = DBConnection.getDBConnection();

            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome to Mysql Server!\n Server Version: " + conn.ServerVersion);
            conn.Close();



        }
```

and my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name ="dbconn" connectionString=""/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I believe that my issue is with the foreach loop, specifically with the doc.elements and the following .element. I believe my knowledge is lacking in what I need to do to point to the right sections of the XML document. I have tried changing the loop even removing it, but at this point I'm certain it needs to be there.

I am using winforms and .net version 5.

Comment: What happens if your program crashes (after you modified app.config and before you change it back).  BTW, at runtime, there is no `app.config` involved.  Your config file is likely named `YourProgramName.exe.config`.  If you are entering the username and password explicitly in your app, why do you think you need to persist your connection string in a config file.  There's no requirement that connection strings come from config files; they can come from anywhere, or you can make them up on the fly.  A connection string is just that - a string

Comment: `I don't want the connection string to be saved in plain text in the XML file` you're doing the exact opposite in your example. Passwords should be hashed + salt. If you want to go this route, create a new class that has the properties you need and then you can serialize that class. [More here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/how-to-write-object-data-to-an-xml-file) about that.

Comment: I should clarify, I have a separate class that builds the mysql connection. So that way as I add additional functionality I don't have to hard code the connection string, but rather that class reads the XML document and grabs the connection string. Then I can just call that and add it when needed. Plus since perms can be adjusted server side the connection string would contain the user's correct permissions.

Comment: @zaggler isn't the connection string plain text when the program runs anyway? My understanding was that the connection string, even encrypted, needs to be plain text for usage within the program. Which is why when dormant, the connection string would be blank, but only be created at runtime, then return to blank. I suppose then a variable would work fior that purpose.

Comment: Make that class available to all your MySql clients.  It builds the string dynamically and holds on to it.  Other code that needs access to the string just calls into that class.  Singletons are generally frowned upon, but this is a great example of where one would be handy.  Do it right, and you can make it (dependency) injectable, so you can have a different instance used for testing.  Just don't persist the string in clear text to the file system.

Comment: @Flydog57 So i'm just thinking then I could pass the connection string from the string builder to a class to hold while the program is running. The class would be callable from other parts of the program that need it. Then at program exit the string vanishes because the "holding" class by default is empty. Nothing gets saved in the file system because there isnt need for it. If i'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: Yes.  That's the idea.

Comment: @Flydog57 +1 to you! I should be able to build this out.